# Command output printed instead of captured in Powershell

Tags: powershell, stdout, subcommand

In general, I know how to capture the output of a command into a variable in Powershell:

```
> $output = python3 --version
> Write-Host $output
Python 3.7.0
```

Python 3 prints its version but it's captured into the variable `$output` and nothing is displayed on the console. As expected:

```
> $output = python3 --version
> Write-Host $output
Python 3.7.0
```

But in the case of Python 2, it doesn't work. Python 2 prints its version but its displayed on the console instead of captured and the variable `$output` is empty.

```
> $output = python2 --version
Python 2.7.15
> Write-Host $output

>
```

I have tried some alternative syntaxes but so far nothing helped:

```
> $output = (python2 --version)  # use a subcommand
Python 2.7.15
> $output = "$(python2 --version)"  # enclose the subcommand into a string
Python 2.7.15
```

If I use it in `Write-Command`, the output looks like the following:

```
> Write-Host "Python version: $(python2 --version)"
Python 2.7.15
Python version:
>
```

How is Python 2 printing its version that it's not captured into a variable and is it possible to capture it anyhow?

Comment: It's likely writing to `stderr`, you can capture the output with `-ErrorVariable varname` or by merging `stderr` into `stdout`: `python2 --version 2>&1`

Comment: OMG, you're right! I wouldn't expect the version number to be printed to `stderr`, it doesn't make a sense to me. It's working fine when I merge both streams. In case of the `-ErrorVariable` option - that's an option of what command, please?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen One more issue: when I run `python2 --version`, command status `$?` is `True` but when I run `python2 --version 2>&1`, the command status is `False`. Why is that? I need that command to be successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by **Python 2 which prints version to `stderr` instead of `stdout`**. Assignment of program call's output captures `stdout` only which is empty in this case. On the other side, `stderr` is printed to the console by default, that's why the `$output` variable is empty and the version is printed to the console. See below for details.

**tl; dr:**

```
# Redirect stderr to the success output stream and convert to a string.
$output = (python --version 2>&1).ToString()
# $? is now $True if python could be invoked, and $False otherwise
```

**For commands that may return *multiple* stderr lines**, use:

- PSv4+, using the `.ForEach()` *method*:

  ```
  $output = (python --version 2>&1).ForEach('ToString')
  ```
- PSv3-, using the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet* (whose built-in alias is `%`):

  ```
  # Note: The (...) around the python call are required for
  #       $? to have the expected value.
  $output = (python --version 2>&1) | % { $_.ToString() }

  # Shorter PSv3+ equivalent, using an operation statement
  $output = (python --version 2>&1) | % ToString
  ```

---

- As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes in a comment on the question and you yourself clarified in terms of versions, **`python` *2.x* - surprisingly - outputs its version information to *stderr*** rather than stdout, unlike *3.x*.
- The reason you weren't able to capture the output with `$output = ...` is that **assigning an *external program* call's output to a variable only captures its *stdout* output** by default.

  - With a *PowerShell-native command*, it captures the command's *success output stream* - see [about_redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).
- The **primary fix is to use redirection `2>&1`** to merge PowerShell's error stream (PowerShell's analog to stderr, to which stderr output is mapped *if redirected*) into PowerShell's success output stream (the stdout analog), which is then captured in the variable.
  This has two side effects, however:

  - Since PowerShell's error stream is now involved due to the `2>&1` redirection (by default, stderr output is *passed through to the console*), **`$?` is invariably set to `$False`**, because writing anything to the error stream does that (even if the error stream is ultimately sent elsewhere, as in this case).

    - Note that `$?` is *not* set to `$False` *without* the redirection (except in the ISE, which is [an unfortunate discrepancy](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996)), because stderr output then never "touches" PowerShell's error output stream.
      **In the PowerShell console, when calling an external program without a `2>` redirection, `$?` is set to `$False` *only* is if its *exit code* is *nonzero* (`$LASTEXITCODE -ne 0`).**
    - Therefore, use of `2>&1` solves one problem (inability capture output) while introducing another (`$?` incorrectly set to `$False`) - see below for a remedy.
  - **It isn't *strings* that get written to the success output stream**, but `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances, because PowerShell wraps every stderr output line in one.
  - If you only use these instances in a *string* context - e.g., `"Version: $output"`, you may not notice or care, however.
- `.ToString()` (for a single output line) and `.ForEach('ToString')` / `(...) | % ToString` (for potentially multiple output lines) undo both side effects:

  - They convert the `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances back to *strings*.
  - They reset `$?` to `$True`, because the `.ToString()` / `.ForEach()` calls / the use of `(...)` around the command are *expressions*, which are themselves considered successful, even if they contain *commands* that themselves set `$?` to `$False`.

Note:

- If executable `python` cannot be located, PowerShell itself will throw a statement-terminating error, which means that the assignment to `$output` will be *skipped* (its value, if any existed, will not change), and by default you get noisy error output and `$?` will be set to `$False`.
- If `python` *can* be invoked and *it* reports an error (which is unlikely with `--version`), as indicated via nonzero *exit code*, you can inspect that exit code via the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable (whose value won't change until the next call to an *external program*).
- That something as simple as putting `(...)` around a command makes `$?` invariably return `$True` (except if a statement- or script-terminating error occurs) is taken advantage of in the above approaches, but is generally obscure behavior that could be considered problematic - see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3359).

Comment: Thanks, @DawidFerenczy.